# Localhost wildcard SSL with Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, puma

I have a Rails 6.0 app with Puma 4.3. I need to set up a wildcard SSL certificate using a custom domain. I've looked at a bunch of different resources out there but I can't seem to get anything working correctly. Most everything I've seen out there caters to non-wildcard setups.

Here is my `config/puma.rb`. I've tried the current configurations as well as the stuff that is commented out.

```
##
# Configure Puma server

require 'fileutils'
workers Integer(ENV.fetch('WEB_CONCURRENCY', 2))
threads_count = Integer(ENV.fetch('MAX_THREADS', 5))
threads threads_count, threads_count

key  = %w[. config ssl myapp-local.com.key].join('/')
crt = %w[. config ssl myapp-local.com.crt].join('/')
ssl_bind '127.0.0.1', '9292', {
  key:         key,
  cert:        crt,
  verify_mode: :peer
}
# if ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'development'
#   unless File.exist?(key)
#     def generate_root_cert(root_key)
#       root_ca = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
#       root_ca.version = 2 # cf. RFC 5280 - to make it a "v3" certificate
#       root_ca.serial = 0x0
#       root_ca.subject = OpenSSL::X509::Name.parse "/C=BE/O=A1/OU=A/CN=*.myapp-local.com"
#       root_ca.issuer = root_ca.subject # root CA's are "self-signed"
#       root_ca.public_key = root_key.public_key
#       root_ca.not_before = Time.now
#       root_ca.not_after = root_ca.not_before + 2 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 # 2 years validity
#
#       root_ca.sign(root_key, OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new)
#       root_ca
#     end
#
#     root_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(2048)
#     file = File.new(key, "wb")
#     file.write(root_key)
#     file.close
#
#     root_cert = generate_root_cert(root_key)
#
#     file = File.new(cert, "wb")
#     file.write(root_cert)
#     file.close
#   end
#
#   ssl_bind '127.0.0.1', '9292', {
#     key:         key,
#     cert:        cert,
#     verify_mode: :peer
#   }
#
#   puts "Using local SSL cert..."
# end

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV.fetch('PORT', 3000)
environment ENV.fetch('RACK_ENV', 'development')

on_worker_boot do
    ##
    # Force Scout Agent launch. Required because of use of nginx in Procfile
    ScoutApm::Agent.instance.start_background_worker
end

on_worker_fork { FileUtils.touch('/tmp/app-initialized') }
```

I'm using `foreman`. Here is my `Procfile.dev`:

```
redis: (ps aux | grep 6379 | grep redis | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -s SIGINT) && redis-server --port 6379
resque: rake resque:workers QUEUE='*' COUNT='5'
scheduler: rake resque:scheduler
web: puma
```

Then in `/etc/hosts` I have:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 app.myapp-local.com
```

When I go to `https://app.myapp-local.com:3000` I get an `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error from Chrome.

I've also tried manually generating the certificate like so:

```
name=myapp-local.com
openssl req \
  -new \
  -newkey rsa:2048 \
  -sha256 \
  -days 3650 \
  -nodes \
  -x509 \
  -keyout $name.key \
  -out $name.crt \
  -config <(cat <<-EOF
  [req]
  distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
  x509_extensions = v3_req
  prompt = no
  [req_distinguished_name]
  CN = $name
  [v3_req]
  keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
  extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
  subjectAltName = @alt_names
  [alt_names]
  DNS.1 = $name
  DNS.2 = *.$name
EOF
)

mv myapp-local.com.crt myapp-local.com.key config/ssl
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain config/ssl/myapp-local.com.crt
```

I've run out of ideas. I can't use a different hostname (e.g. lvh.me or localhost) because of how the app is configured, so I need it to work with `*.myapp-local.com:3000`. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

So I changed my config file like so:

```
if ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'development'
  key  = %w[. config ssl myapp-local.com.key].join('/')
  crt  = %w[. config ssl myapp-local.com.pem].join('/')
  ca   = "/Users/Daniel Bonnell/Library/Application\ Support/Certificate\ Authority/myapp/myapp.certAuthorityConfig"

  ssl_bind '127.0.0.1', '3000', {
    key:         key,
    cert:        crt,
    ca:          ca,
    verify_mode: :peer
  }
end
```

Now when I boot the app I see this in the logs:

```
17:12:45 web.1 | [68495] * Listening on ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?cert=./config/ssl/myapp-local.com.pem&key=./config/ssl/myapp-local.com.key&verify_mode=peer&no_tlsv1=false&no_tlsv1_1=false&ca=/Users/Daniel Bonnell/Library/Application Support/Certificate Authority/myapp/myapp.certAuthorityConfig
17:12:45 web.1 | [68495] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:5300
```

If I go to `https://app.myapp-local.com:3000` I see the following error:

```
17:14:19 web.1 | 2020-03-28 17:14:19 -0500: SSL error, peer: 127.0.0.1, peer cert: /O=member: F4B00436-9C90-4941-B053-A83BCB633934 DD31B694-6F02-4C8D-98C2-640DABBEB3F8/CN=member: F4B00436-9C90-4941-B053-A83BCB633934 DD31B694-6F02-4C8D-98C2-640DABBEB3F8, #<Puma::MiniSSL::SSLError: OpenSSL certificate verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate - 20>
```

If I go to `https://app.myapp-local.com:5300` I see the following error:

```
17:15:32 web.1 | 2020-03-28 17:15:32 -0500: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>
```

I followed [these steps](https://blog.filippo.io/mkcert-valid-https-certificates-for-localhost/) using `mkcert` to generate a certificate and then I set up a local CA in my keychain (MacOS).

Comment: *"When I go to https://app.myapp-local.com:3000 I get an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error from Chrome."* - it looks for me like your config is doing plain HTTP on port 3000 while SSL is done on port 9292. This would explain the error you see, i.e. HTTPS access to a port not capable of HTTPS.

Comment: I just updated my question. I tried a new configuration with a local CA. I think I'm getting closer but now there seems to be some kind of issue with my certificate? I've checked and nothing is running on port 9292. It looks like only 3000 and 5300 (not sure where this port is coming from) are in use.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get my setup working correctly. I think there were two problems. First, I was binding SSL to port 3000 and then further down, binding Puma to port 3000. I changed `port        ENV.fetch('PORT', 3000)` to `port        ENV.fetch('PORT', 3001)`. Second, I was pointing to the wrong CA. The setup below seems to work for me now. I can access my app on port 3000 and I no longer see that pesky SSL error. Hope this helps someone. I spent 10 hours figuring it out.

```
##
# Configure Puma server

require 'fileutils'
workers Integer(ENV.fetch('WEB_CONCURRENCY', 2))
threads_count = Integer(ENV.fetch('MAX_THREADS', 5))
threads threads_count, threads_count

# Note: Must generate an SSL certificate for local use.
# See: https://blog.filippo.io/mkcert-valid-https-certificates-for-localhost/
if ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'development'
  key  = File.expand_path('./config/ssl/local_key.pem')
  crt  = File.expand_path('./config/ssl/local_cert.pem')
  ca   = File.expand_path('~/Library/Application Support/mkcert/rootCA.pem')

  ssl_bind '127.0.0.1', 3000, {
    key:         key,
    cert:        crt,
    ca:          ca,
    verify_mode: :peer
  }
end

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV.fetch('PORT', 3001)
environment ENV.fetch('RACK_ENV', 'development')

on_worker_boot do
    ##
    # Force Scout Agent launch. Required because of use of nginx in Procfile
    ScoutApm::Agent.instance.start_background_worker
end

on_worker_fork { FileUtils.touch('/tmp/app-initialized') }
```